# Catch-all command to restart display manager?

Tags: x11, init-script, display-manager

Is there a catch-all command to restart display managers (on any given common init system)?

I've got `systemctl restart display-manager` for systemd-based systems currently, but I don't know that that'll work on *every* systemd-based system, and it sure won't work on *other* init systems.

Are there other catch-all commands that are likely to work (given that a particular common init system is installed on a common distro)?

Comment: in the traditional init system, switching from runlevel 5 to runlevel 3 and back is probably the closest you'll find to a generic means of stopping and starting the display manager.  this could fail in systems that chose not to follow the conventional runlevel definitions.  i don't know how well this translates to the various modern init systems.

Comment: @quixotic that would also stop and restart a lot of other things that had nothing to do with the display manager.   I don't think there's any generic solution that will always work - even Bigon's answer will only work sometimes (probably even most of the time - when the base filename of the display-manager's executable is identical to the service name....works for, e.g., lightdm and gdm.  It may not work for others)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Debian (and derivatives like ubuntu), `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` should contain the name of the currently active display manager.

So something like that should work:

```
dm=$(basename "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager)")
service $dm restart
```

Otherwise, I don't think there is a standardized way of doing so